# Clang command to compile raylib

Tags: c, clang, raylib

I'm new to clang and am trying to get it to compile raylib. I haven't found anything online to do this (anything clang on the internet seems to be hidden). All I need is a command to compile raylib to a dll (I know how to link that with my own program).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the build-environment with cmake and specify that you want to use the clang compiler like:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/bin/clang" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="/bin/clang"
```

This will generate you a makefile which will use clang. Make sure that clang is installed correctly and that the configured folders to clang are correct on your machine.

Comment: Thank you so much, It comes with a make file but I thought that was for a different compiler.

Comment: Right, I missed a -D option for the compiler setup.